# Compact Formula for Wigner D-matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

I have done an elementary calculation that appears to be giving me a simple (intuitive) formula for an arbitrary Wigner D-matrix. I can't seem to find this formula anywhere.

In the following, $\mathscr{R}$ represents an active rotation, $\Omega$ is solid angle, and $|\Omega\rangle$ are an orthonormal basis.

$$\begin{align}
D^{l}_{m,m'}(\mathscr{R})&=\langle l,m'|\mathscr{R}|l,m\rangle\\
&=\int d\Omega\,\langle l,m'|\mathscr{R}|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|l,m\rangle\\
&=\int d\Omega\,\langle l,m'|\mathscr{R}\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|l,m\rangle\\
&=\int d\Omega\, \,Y_l^{m'*}(\mathscr{R}\Omega)\,Y_l^m(\Omega)
\end{align}$$

So it's a convolution of spherical harmonics. Is this right? I know my calculation is a bit cavalier but they seem more-or-less sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything cavalier about this calculation.<sup>(*)</sup>  You can verify it from another direction using the rotation law for the (conjugate of the) spherical harmonic:
\begin{equation}
  \bar{Y}^{m'}_\ell(\mathscr{R}\Omega) = \sum_{m''} D^{(\ell)}_{m'',m'}(\mathscr{R})\, \bar{Y}^{m''}_\ell(\Omega).
\end{equation}
Insert this into your expression and use orthogonality of the spherical harmonics to find your result the other way around:
\begin{align}
  \int d\Omega\, \,Y_l^{m'*}(\mathscr{R}\Omega)\,Y_l^m(\Omega)
  &=
  \sum_{m''} \left[ \int d\Omega\, D^{(\ell)}_{m'',m'}(\mathscr{R})\, \bar{Y}^{m''}_\ell(\Omega)\, Y_l^m(\Omega) \right] \\
  &=
  \sum_{m''} \left[ D^{(\ell)}_{m'',m'}(\mathscr{R})\, \int d\Omega\, \bar{Y}^{m''}_\ell(\Omega)\, Y_l^m(\Omega) \right] \\
  &=
  \sum_{m''} \left[ D^{(\ell)}_{m'',m'}(\mathscr{R})\, \delta_{m, m''} \right] \\
  &=
  D^{(\ell)}_{m,m'}(\mathscr{R}).
\end{align}
Of course, the logic works exactly the same if you go backwards in this sequence, so now that you see how it's done, you can also use this as a derivation of your result.

The bigger question is why this is useful.  Usually, an expression like your last integral would arise when you're trying to evaluate the spherical-harmonic modes of a function in a rotated coordinate system.  But we already know how to rotate modes.  If you're suggesting that this might be an easier way to actually calculate the $D$ matrices, or just a simpler way to define them, I'm skeptical.  But it's certainly another valid way to think of them, if you like.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> My one quibble is that I'm not sure that the order of your $m, m'$ indices is standard.  Then again, I've never seen much consistency at all about any conventions involved in rotations.  I've tried to stick with your ordering as best I can.  But if you see swapper indices, that's probably why.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression relies on the relation
$$
D^\ell_{m0}(\alpha,\beta,0)= \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2\ell+1}} Y_\ell^{m*}(\beta,\alpha)
$$
so that you get 
\begin{align}
&\int \sin\beta d\beta\,d\alpha \frac{2\ell+1}{4\pi}
D^\ell_{m'0}(\omega\cdot(\alpha,\beta,0))D^{\ell*}_{m0}(\alpha,\beta,0)\, ,\\
&=\sum_{k}
\int \sin\beta d\beta\,d\alpha \frac{2\ell+1}{4\pi}
D^\ell_{m'k}(\omega)D^\ell_{k0}(\alpha,\beta,0))D^{\ell*}_{m0}(\alpha,\beta,0)\, ,\\
&=\sum_{k}D^\ell_{m'k}(\omega)\frac{2\ell+1}{4\pi}
\int \sin\beta d\beta\,d\alpha 
D^\ell_{k0}(\alpha,\beta,0))D^{\ell*}_{m0}(\alpha,\beta,0)\, 
\end{align}
The integral is proportional to $\delta_{km}$ so the result is indeed $D^{\ell}_{m'k}(\omega)$.

Given there are [closed form expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) for $D^{\ell}_{m'k}(\omega)$, and given it is defined quite intuitively by 
$$
D^{\ell}_{m'k}(\omega) = \langle \ell m'\vert R(\omega)\vert \ell k\rangle
$$
I'm not sure what is gained by expressing this as a convolution.