# What are spherical tensors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, definition, spherical-harmonics

Following Sakurai, I know how the Cartesian components of a tensor transform under rotation, in classical physics and also in quantum physics. For example, the Cartesian components of a vector change as $$V^{\prime}_i= R_{ij} V_j$$ and the Cartesian components of the corresponding vector operator transform according to $$\hat{D}^\dagger(R)\hat{V}_i\hat{D}(R)=R_{ij}\hat{V}_j.$$ This can be generalized to Cartesian components of tensors of higher ranks. In particular, the Cartesian components of a tensor of rank-$k$ transform under the rotation as$$T_{i_1i_2...i_k}^\prime=R_{i_1j_1}R_{i_2j_2}...R_{i_kj_k}T_{j_1j_2...j_k}$$ and the corresponding Cartesian components of the tensor operator
transform under the rotation according to
$$D^\dagger(R)T_{i_1i_2...i_k} D(R)=R_{i_1j_1}R_{i_2j_2}...R_{i_kj_k}T_{j_1j_2...j_k}.$$

Sakurai tells us how the spherical tensor operators $\hat{T}^{(k)}_q$ in quantum mechanics. A spherical tensor of rank-$k$ is a set of $(2k+1)$ operators whose components transform under rotation as (Sakurai) $$\hat{D}^\dagger(R) \hat{T}^{(k)}_q\hat{D}(R)=\sum\limits_{q'=-k}^{k}D_{qq'}^{(k)*}\hat{T}_{q'}^{(k)}$$ or
$$\hat{D}(R) \hat{T}^{(k)}_q\hat{D}^\dagger(R)=\sum\limits_{q'=-k}^{k}D_{q'q}^{(k)}\hat{T}_{q'}^{(k)}.$$
where these $\hat{D}(R)$'s are unitary representations of $R\in SO(3)$ in the appropriate ket space of the quantum system.

*But what is a spherical tensor $T^{(k)}_q$ (not a spherical tensor **operator**, $\hat{T}^{(k)}_q$) in classical physics?* For irreducible spherical tensors of rank-$k$, I would expect that under rotation the following should be the case:
$$T^{(k)}_q\stackrel{R}{\rightarrow} \sum_{q'=-k}^{k}C^{(k)}_{qq'}T^{(k)}_{q'}.$$ But if this is the case, how are the coefficients $C^{(k)}_{qq'}$ related to $R_{ij}$?

Comment: Perhaps you could state what you know them to be in quantum. Probably if you do that, you'll understand what they are in classical.

Comment: @DanielSank Please tell me if the question is clear.

Answer (score 3):

According to the **Peter-Weyl theorem**, if $G$ is a *compact topological group*, then every *strongly continuous unitary representation* $G\ni g \mapsto U_g$ in  a fixed *Hilbert space* ${\cal H}$ is the orthogonal direct sum of a suitable family of *finite-dimensional* *irreducible* unitary representation $G \ni g \mapsto U^{(j)}_g$.

The representations of this family are pairwise unitarily inequivalent.

In other words, ${\cal H}$ decomposes into an orthogonal sum made of *finite dimensional* subspaces ${\cal H}_k \subset {\cal H}$:
$${\cal H} = \oplus_{k\in H} {\cal H}_k$$
(infinite if ${\cal H}$ is infinite dimensionall) with $U_g({\cal H}_k) \subset {\cal H}_k$ and $U_g|_{{\cal H}_k}= U_g^{(j_k)}$ (up to unitary equivalence). Notice that a representation $U^{(j)}$ may appear several times as we can have $j_k=j_{k'}$. Evidently
if ${\cal H}_{k}$ and ${\cal H}_{k'}$ are unitarily isomorphic in that case and the abstract space where $U^{(j_k)}\equiv U^{(j_k)}$ acts is indicated by ${\cal H}^{(j)}$.

The finite dimensional representations $U^{(j)}$ (defined up to unitary equivalence) are the building blocks to construct all possible continuous unitary representations of $G$.

Now let us focus on a given $U^{(j)}$ and let us fix an orthonormal basis in the space ${\cal H}^{(j)} \equiv \mathbb{C}^{d_j}$. As every $U_g^{(j)}$ is unitary, it can be viewed as a unitary marix of coefficients  $D^{(j)}(g)_{nm}$. These matrices can be viewed as matrices connecting different orthonormal frames in ${\cal H}^{(j)}$, since they are unitary matrices.

In the very special case of $G=SU(2)$, all elementary irreducible (finite dimensional) matrices $D^{(j)}(g)_{mn}$ are classified. As a matter of fact $j=0,1/2,1, 3/2, 2, \ldots$ and $d_j=2j+1$.

A vector  $T^{(j)} \in {\cal H}^{(j)}\equiv \mathbb{C}^{2j+1}$ has components $T^{(j)}_{m}$, $m=1,2, \ldots, 2j+1$, such that, changing orthonormal basis connected by the matrices $D^{(j)}(g)$ transforms as
$$T'^j_{m} = \sum_{n=1}^{2j+1} D^{(j)}_{mn}(g) T^j_n\:. \tag{1}$$

*A **spherical tensor of order $j$** is noting but a vector in ${\cal H}^{(j)}$ when the reference group is $G:=SU(2)$.*

In view of this definition, its components transforms as in (1) when we change orthogonal basis and these basis are connected by the corresponding representation of $SU(2)$. We can also suppose to deal with a fixed basis. In that case (1) describes the **active** action of $SU(2)$ on these vectors.

An important point is that, if $j=0,1,2,...$ then $U^{(j)}$ is **also** a representation of $SO(3)$, since the covering map $\pi : SU(2) \ni g \mapsto R_g \in SO(3)$ has the nice property that, for $R\in SO(3)$ and $j\in \mathbb{N}$
$$SO(3) \ni R \mapsto V^{(j)}_R := U^{(j)}_{\pi^{-1}(R)}$$
is well defined and defines a group representation.

For $j=1$, ${\cal H}^{(1)} \equiv {\mathbb C}^3$ and the matrices $D^{1}$ can be chosen (working in a suitable orthonormal basis of $ {\mathbb C}^3$) as the well-known matrices which represent the rotations of spherical harmonics. In this picture ${\cal H}^{(1)}$ is a subspace of $L^2(S^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a spherical tensor $T^{(k)}_q$. This object rotates under rotation $R$ as

$$
T'^{(k)}_q = \sum_{q'=-k}^kD(R)_{q, q'}^k T^{(k)}_{q'}
$$

Where $D(R)^k_{q, q'}$ is the [Wigner D-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) for rotation $R$.
The link provides explicit (albeit complicated) formulas relating $D(R)^k_{q, q'}$ to $R$. (There's a chance I've gotten $q$ and $q'$ swapped around in the subscripts).

A spherical tensor of rank $k$ is a group of $2k+1$ numbers which transform in the same way under rotations as the $2k+1$ [spherical harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) of rank $k$ transform amongst each other under rotation.

I'd suggest replacing the $\hat{D}(R)$ you are using with $U(R)$ or $\hat{U}(R)$. $R$ is the rotation matrix, $D(R)$ is the Wigner D-matrix corresponding to that rotation, and $U(R)$ is the unitary matrix which is a representation of that matrix on the quantum Hilbert space. These are three highly related, but distinct objects.

Comment: Here is my problem. Can't we talk about spherical tensors without talking about quantum mechanics? If the definition is in terms of $D(R)$ (or $U(R)$, in your notation), suggests to me that we are using the knowledge of quantum mechanics to define a spherical tensor. This is weird! Certainly, for defining how Cartesian components of a tensor transform, we didn't need that.

Comment: @Solidification No, $D(R)^k_{q, q'}$ does not require quantum mechanics to define. It does not require $U(R)$. $D(R)^k_{q, q'}$ can be defined in terms of transformation properties of spherical harmonics which are the family of solutions on the sphere of a certain differential equation which *can* arise in contexts unrelated to quantum mechanics

Comment: $D(R)^k_{q, q'}$ is a just a $2k+1 \times 2k+1$ array, similar to how $R$ is a $3\times 3$ array

Comment: "...can be defined in terms of transformation properties of spherical harmonics" Is there a reference where a discussion can be found?

Comment: @Solidification so it's a well known fact or definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Relation_to_spherical_harmonics_and_Legendre_polynomials) that $Y_l^{'m} = Y_l^{m'} D^l_{m', m}$ But it does remain to be seen if we can use this relation to "straight-forwardly" *derive* an explicit formula for $D^l_{m', m}$. I imagine it should be possible, but I don't know how to do it and I don't have a reference off-hand. Or at least not one that moves into group theory, hilbert spaces, and representation theory (which I think is to be avoided per the spirit of the question..)

Comment: Using the formula I've given and orthogonal you can see that $D$ is directly related to the overlap integral between $Y_l^m$ and a rotated version of $Y_l^{m'}$. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383594/compact-formula-for-wigner-d-matrix. If this integral can be used to calculate the explicit formula on the linked Wikipedia page, I'm not sure.

Comment: But I guess I'll emphasize that the *definition* of $D^k_{q, q'}$ as the matrix elements for rotations of spherical harmonics need not have ANYTHING to do with quantum mechanics. Also, once we have spherical harmonics, we could calculate the elements of $D$ numerically if needed. The fact that analytic methods/tricks used to give an analytic expression for $D$ us notations and intuitions from quantum mechanics doesn't mean we NEED quantum mechanics to understand $D^k_{q,q'}$ or spherical tesnors.

Comment: Thanks, your comments are very helpful in clearing some dust. I'll have to do some reading before I can come back to accept the answer :-) I have to convince myself that Sakurai's derivation of how spherical harmonics transform has nothing to do with quantum mechanics (though it uses "bra and ket" language to derive the transformation of spherical harmonics under rotation).

Comment: @Solidification. Think of the (Cartesian) inertia tensor in class.mech, and remove the trace (which is invariant under rotation).  What's left can be expressed in terms of components of a spherical tensor with $L=2$.  If you rotate the coordinate system, the Cartesian components of the inertia tensors will rotate one into a linear combo of the others, as will the spherical components.  The difference is that the combos for the spherical case are $D^2_{mm'}$ functions.